# How to do such a footer and header in LaTeX?

Tags: header-footer, templates, ieee-style

I guess it is possible to do it somehow I tried as follows, however I was not able to do it yet. Can anyone help me to get exactly this header and footer?

From even to odd:

[image]

From odd to even:

[image]

That's what I tried:

```
\documentclass[twoside,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyfoot[LE]{January/February 2013}
\fancyfoot[CE]{Copublished by the IEEE Computer and Reliability Societies}
\fancyfoot[RE]{1540-7993/15/\$31.00 2015 IEEE}

\fancyhead[LO,RE]{bar}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document} 

\pagenumbering{arabic} 
\begin{multicols}{2}    
\lipsum[3-20]
\end{multicols} 
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With  a KOMA-class, package `scrlayer-scrpage` should be used. Usage of `fancyhdr` is heavily discouraged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another suggestion using `scrlayer-scrpage`

```
\documentclass[twoside,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\pagenumberspace{3em}
\usepackage[
  headwidth=paper,
  footwidth=\the\textwidth+\pagenumberspace:0pt,
  headtopline=.5pt,
  headsepline=.5pt,
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearscrheadfoot
\lehead*{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{3em}{\headheight}\quad BAR}
\rohead*{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{3em}{\headheight}}

\lefoot*{\makebox[0pt][l]{\pagemark}{\normalsize\hspace*{\pagenumberspace}}%
               January/February 2013}
\cefoot*{Copublished by the IEEE Computer and Reliability Societies}
\refoot*{1540-7993/15/\$31.00 2015 IEEE}

\lofoot*{www.wherever}
\cofoot*{}
\rofoot*{\pagemark}%

\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\color{blue!50!green}}
\addtokomafont{pagefoot}{\tiny}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\normalsize\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[3-20]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\textbf{\thepage}\hspace{3em}}%
               \tiny January/February 2013}
\fancyfoot[CE]{\tiny Copublished by the IEEE Computer and Reliability Societies}
\fancyfoot[RE]{\tiny 1540-7993/15/\$31.00 2015 IEEE}

\fancyhead[LO,RE]{bar}
\fancyfoot[LO]{\tiny www.wherever}
\fancyfoot[CO]{}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{3em}\textbf{\thepage}}}%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document} 

\pagenumbering{arabic} 
\begin{multicols}{2}    
\lipsum[3-20]
\end{multicols} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Same content as David's but using `scrlayer-scrpage` which is recommended with KOMA classes. Better not use `fancyhdr` here.

```
\documentclass[twoside,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\lefoot*{\makebox[0pt][r]{\textbf{\thepage}\hspace{3em}}%
               \tiny January/February 2013}
\cefoot*{\tiny Copublished by the IEEE Computer and Reliability Societies}
\refoot*{\tiny 1540-7993/15/\$31.00 2015 IEEE}

\ihead*{bar}
\lofoot*{\tiny www.wherever}
\cofoot*{}
\rofoot*{\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{3em}\textbf{\thepage}}}%
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[3-20]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`*` in `\cofoot` etc makes the arguments appear on `plain scrheadings` settings also. For details, read KOMA manual (`texdoc scrguien` or www.texdoc.net) chapter 5 page 203 onwards.

Comment: You can use `setkomafont` or `addtokomafont` to make them `\tiny` etc. For details, see manual.